# convert 090216 (string) into 16-FEB-09 (date) in hive

Tags: datetime, hive, hiveql

so I am trying to convert
`0902160918 (string)`
into
`16-FEB-09`

My current work:

```
SELECT
  date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(SUBSTR(DATE_TIME,1,6),'yyMMdd'),'yy-MMM-dd'))    
FROM 
  table_name
      ;
```

What is the best practice to convert this? Should I input `concat` or something?

All helps or ideas surely will be appriciated.

Comment: Unbelievable that people still store only 2 digits for year. Did you never hear about the [Y2K Bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem)?

Comment: no. the data is subquery of other, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query could also work if you fixed some brackets:

```
select date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(substr(DATE_TIME, 1, 6) ,'yyMMdd')),'dd-MMM-yy') FROM table_name;
```

or

```
select date_format(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(DATE_TIME, 'yyMMddHHmm')),'dd-MMM-yy') FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225912/discussion-on-answer-by-mck-convert-090216-string-into-16-feb-09-date-in-hiv).